# Client certificates, signalr hubs and mixed net- Blazor wasm clients

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, webassembly, .net-7.0, client-certificates

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 project with two SignalR hubs in an app hosted under IIS. One will have JWT auth, the other should have client cert - only validation, no user mapping or such.

I have only access to web.config and kestrel, the IIS itself is off-limits. The template Blazor wasm project works with a basic SignalR hub connection.

As intended, one hub will be addressed by .net clients only (this should require cert), the other by Blazor wasm clients only (if these can provide cert, than great, but if this is not an option, then, this later hub should be connectable without a cert)

1. Can I use code-supplied client cert from browser-wasm? I can't install client cert as this will be a PWA.
2. If not, how can I setup my server side to require and accept cert from the .NET Core SignalR client on one hub, but not to fail if the WASM client can't supply any on the other hub.
3. How can I validate client cert only on the hub that should require one? And not on the other.

Comment: ASP.NET Core doesn't really use `web.config` except for setting-up the `ASPNetCoreModuleV2` btw.

Comment: _"Can I use code-supplied client cert from browser-wasm? I can't install client cert as this will be a PWA."_ - Web-browsers generally don't use client-certificates (outside of controlled Enterprise environments). Blazor+WASM will mean using Cookies or a Bearer Token (note that SPAs _cannot_ store secrets (like bearer-tokens) securely) hence why  you'll likely end-up needing to proxy all requests through ASP.NET Core anyway...)

Comment: @Dai, I know that blazor wasm app runs in a browser sandbox. That's why I am asking, since the WS conection is backed by fetch api, which is quite a limitation. Anyway, the cert from the PWA side would have been a nice to have anyway. But then I need to set up the server to require and accept certs but not reject if not provided.

Comment: There is this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-your-server-to-require-certificates but I am not sure if that will work even if I set both to "Accept".

Btw: when hosted on IIS (as in my scenario), ASPNetCoreModuleV2 is there - so anything that is not restricted from the upper level can and needs to be set in web.config. And I can't add a proxy. I have the IIS and that's it.